# Method error while rendering comments to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Comment` model that belongs both to `Post` and `User` (`User` model is custom, and authenticates via `omniauth`). So, I can't manage out how to fix an error in `_comment.html.erb`: it returns `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'avatar_url' for nil:NilClass)`. here's the code:

**post.rb**

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many: comments, dependent: :destroy
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth)
        provider = auth.provider
        uid = auth.uid
        info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
        user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
        user.name = info.name
        user.avatar_url = info.image
        user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
        user.save!
        user
    end
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create
end

def create
    if current_user
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)
    end
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.avatar_url, 
         alt: comment.user.name, class: "media-object"),
         comment.user.profile_url, target: '_blank', class: 'pull-left' %>
    <h4 class="media-heading">
        <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user.profile_url, target: '_blank' %>
    </h4>
    <p><%= comment.body %></div>
</div>
```

Source code: https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/vilenskaya.git

Comment: How your `_comments.html.erb` gets rendered ?

Comment: @dkp in `show.html.erb` via `<%= render @post.comments %>`

Comment: In `_comments.html.erb`, what does `comment.user` returns ? I guess it would be returning `nil`

Comment: @dkp it should indicate in `comment` the data of `user` whom it belongs

Comment: I have added an `if` statement to check whether `comment` has any `user` or not , can you give it a try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just added an `if` statement in your partial, can you give it a try now:

```
<div>
 <% if comment.user.present? %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.avatar_url, alt: comment.user.name, class: "media-object"),comment.user.profile_url,target: '_blank', class: 'pull-left' %>
  <h4 class="media-heading">
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user.profile_url, target: '_blank' %>
  </h4>
  <p><%= comment.body %></div>
 <% end %> 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! now it doesn't return an error, but just doesn't show the comment. so, there must be an issue that when I leave the comment it doesn't assign my `user` data to it

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 yes, check in your console whether you have a `user_id` column in `comments` table or not ? If it is present then what does it return ?

Comment: I've checked in Postgres console, there's no `user_id` at the comment :(. **EDIT**: `rails c` also returns `user_id: nil`

Comment: ok just quickly do a migration `rails g migration AddUserReferenceToComment user:references` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` - For all your existing comment, you can create a rake task to add values to `user_id` column or same you can do from you console as well.

Comment: it returns an error when migrating a database, because such relationship already exists: `column user_id already exists`. When I created the `comment` model I made it in such a way: `rails g model Comment body:text post:references user:references`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 then you must be having `user_id` column in your `comments` table. you can check from your `rails console` by typing `Comment.column_names`

Comment: yes I do have `user_id` column in comments table. I meant that particular comment that I've created and which isn't displayed has `user_id: nil` and `post_id: 1`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Your `CommentsController` strong param should look like this:  `def comment_params  params.require(:comment).permit(:body,:post_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id)  end`   Then you can create comments as `@comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 glad it helped !! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a user with your comment, so `@comment.user` is nil. I'm guessing comment should be assigned current_user? If so:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(user: current_user) # Depending on what the user is supposed to be
```

Comment: and what about private method overriding strong parameters? I mean `comment_params`, which usually goes in the parentheses after `@post.comments.create`

Comment: Since you're passing a simple hash and not params object, you don't need to whitelist. In other words, you're not processing form params from the user.

Comment: it didn't work, still returns the same `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'avatar_url' for nil:NilClass)` :(

Comment: Sure, that may be helpful.

Comment: You're iterating through all comments in `Post`, so it's likely that at least one  comment in your post is missing a user. I'd also add a validation to require that a comment has both a post and a user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108760/discussion-between-alexnikolaev94-and-anthony-e).